# 2011 Traverse Transmission fluid

Tags: transmission-fluid

I have a 2011 Chevy traverse lt awd and has 132,500 miles on it transmission fluid has never been changed and the color is a light brown and want to change it would it be a bad idea to or would it create a problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's old "mechanic" folklore that changing transmission fluid with an high-mileage transmission will cause a failure.  There is no proof of this that I've ever seen.  I think the problem is that such a transmission is more prone to failure anyway due to its age and mileage.

But a flush and change will help extend the remaining life of the unit and if this were mine, I'd certainly change the fluid.